# Knot invariant in arbitrary 3-manifold

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, knot-theory, quantum-field-theory, knot-invariants

In famous Witten's paper "Quantum Field Theory and Jones Polynomial", Witten proposed

$\int DA \exp{iL} \prod_{k=1}^{r} W_{R_t} (C_i)$

as the knot invariant in ARBITRARY 3-manifold.
($L$ is a Langlangian of Chern-Simons 3-form, and the integral is Feynman path integral of gauge transformation.)

After Witten's paper, Turaev formulated Witten's idia as the quantum invariants. But Quantum invariants are defined only for knots in $S^3$.
Does anyone know "Quantum invariants in arbitrary 3-manifold"?

Cf
1.Witten's paper and Turaev's paper
https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1104178138
http://mathlab.snu.ac.kr/~top/quantum/article/Reshetikhin01.pdf

2.knot theory in $RP^3$
https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0312205.pdf

3.related question
[Unknown Witten-Reshetikhin-Turaev (WRT) Invariants for a 3 Manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2861951/unknown-witten-reshetikhin-turaev-wrt-invariants-for-a-3-manifold)

[Knot theory on arbitrary manifolds.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2902704/knot-theory-on-arbitrary-manifolds)

Comment: The LMO invariant works for rational homology spheres.

Comment: Thank you for pointing. Are there any direct relation between Jones-Witten invariant and LMO invatriant? I think LMO inv comes from analogy of Kontsevich invariant.

Comment: Yes, LMO is a generalization of Kontsevich. I don't know if there is a relation to Jones-Witten.